# I need help with my explosion in bomberman

Tags: javascript

I am trying to recreate bomberman so far i have my players moving i can place bombs the hard part for me is the explosions because i need them to fill out one til to these directions : Right - Left - Up - Down

I found something that might be useful but not sure how to implement it

```
   for (int i = 0; i < explosion.powerUps.power; ++i)
    {
        tiles[actor.tileX - i][actor.tileY].explode(); //left
        tiles[actor.tileX + i][actor.tileY].explode(); //right
        tiles[actor.tileX][actor.tileY -i].explode(); //up
        tiles[actor.tileX][actor.tileY + i].explode(); //down
    }
```

I want to implement this for the explosions....

This is my code now:

```
window.addEventListener('load', pageLoaded);

var keys = {
    keyP1Up: false,
    keyP1Down: false,
    keyP1Right: false,
    keyP1Left: false,
    keyp1Bomb: false,
    keyP2Up: false,
    keyP2Down: false,
    keyP2Right: false,
    keyP2Left: false,
    keyP2Bomb: false,
    muteSound: false
};
var bombTimer = 2000;
var gameSound;
var myText;
var game = {};
var tiles = null;
var lives = 2;
var playerOne;
var playerTwo;
var level = 0;
var explosionSS;
var powerUps = {
    speed: 3,
    bombs: 1,
    power: 1
}
var bomb = {
    width: 59,
    height: 59
}
var playerOneBombs = [];
var playerTwoBombs = [];

function explosion(bomb) {
    game.stage.removeChild(bomb);
    createjs.Sound.play('bombAudio');
    console.log('Explosion sound');
    // Explosion sprite

    var explosionSS = new createjs.SpriteSheet(game.q.getResult('fire'));
    var bombExplosion = new createjs.Sprite(explosionSS, "fire");
    game.stage.addChild(bombExplosion);
    bombExplosion.width = 60;
    bombExplosion.height = 60;
    bombExplosion.x = bomb.x;
    bombExplosion.y = bomb.y;
    bombExplosion.addEventListener('animationend', function () {
        console.log("explosion over");
        game.stage.removeChild(bombExplosion);
    });
    console.log(bombExplosion);
    console.log('explosion');

}
```

I have only put in my code for my Explosions and my vars if needed more just tell me im really stuck and i dont really know how to implement my explosion so it goes to all the directions

Answer (score 1):

You want to make two lines : A vertical one and a horizontal one and make sure the player's cell does not explode.

You want to iterate every cell on the actor's row and make it explode except the actor's cell.

```
for(i = 0; i < GRID_WIDTH; i++)
{
    if(i != actor.x)
        tiles[i][actor.y].explode();
}
```

And you want to do the same thing for the vertical bombing line

```
for(i = 0; i < GRID_HEIGHT; i++)
{
    if(i != actor.y)
        tiles[actor.x][i].explode();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically the example you found is assuming you have an object to represent your tiles.  The tile objects are saved in a matrix and likely contain information on players on the tile, if the tile is passable, and if the tile is currently exploding or not.  You can then use that information to tell when a tile should be playing its explosion animation and also when a player is colliding with an exploding tile.